# WooCommerce | Variable Product | Assign same image to Attribute X (out of Y) per value

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

In WooCommerce variable product, there are attributes and attribute values, which create variations.

```
E.g. :
Attribute: 1 (Size) | Values: XS/S/M/L/XL
Attribute: 2 (Style/Color) | Values: Red/Green/Blue/Black/...
Attribute: 3 (Fabric) | Cotton/Polyester/Some other stuff...
```

Let's assume you have 1 picture per style value.
Let's also assume you have 500 total variations (due to triple attributes, which stacks).

**Is there a simple way to associate a single picture per "ATTRIB2 VALUE" so you don't have to manually edit every single picture from variations?**

100 products with 500 single variations seems like a lot of monkey work, **there has to be a better way**.

Edit: 
1 picture for ALL blue variations; 
1 picture for all red variations... 
etc...

***Side-question:*** Is there a way to use the bulk "Set Regular Price" to apply to ALL variations instead of only the ones on active "page"?

Comment: I add the same need for a bunch of products with all the same 2 variations, same price, same images but if I want to edit the 2 variations I have to edit each product one by one. I ended up using the `WP CLI` `wp search-replace old-price new-price --all-tables` but its quite dangerous since that price could be used somewhere else.

Comment: Have a look at this plugin - https://www.webtoffee.com/product/product-import-export-woocommerce/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me in my test installation:

```
/**
 * Replace Woocommerce Product Variation Images
 * based on variation slug 
 */

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_image_id', 'so_filter_wooc_product_variation_images', 10, 2 ) ;

function so_filter_wooc_product_variation_images( $image_id, $data ) {

    //the variation product slug includes "-black"...
    if ( strpos( $data->slug, '-black') ) { 

        //replace with new image by id number
        return $new_image_id ;

    } 

    //else return the image_id according to default settings
    return $image_id ;

}
```

Now, you don't have search the product slug as I have done here, necessarily: There are other variables that, depending in part on your installation design, may distinguish one set of variable products from another. By default, however, the product slug for a product variation will combine the attribute terms. So, if your product is "Test Product"; you have two sizes, "Big" and "Small," and two colors, "Black" and "White"; they're enabled to produce variations; and the variations are priced (which is required), you'll get product slugs in the format `test-product-big-black` and `test-product-big-white`, and so on, so this seems like a sound method for achieve approximately what you want, focused on the attribute.

It's not, however, a foolproof method: if the attribute name occurs in the item title, then there's some chance of occasional overlap - for, say, a product with the title "Test Black Product." How to solve this issue programmatically is, obviously, a more complicated question: The function I've provided here still illustrates the general concept.

As for `$new_image_id_number`, you could get that in various different ways, so I've left that open. For example, you could just find the attachment ID by hovering over the image you want to use in the Media Library. Alternatively, you could create a site option - the old-fashioned away or maybe with Advanced Custom Fields Pro - and extract the ID from an image upload.

Anyway, this working solution turns out to be fairly simple. The filter hook is based on the protected function in abstract-wc-data.php...

```
$value = apply_filters( $this->get_hook_prefix() . $prop, $value, $this );
```

...which is constructed from the "hook prefix," in this case `woocommerce_product_variation_`, and the property in question, in this case `image_id`.

(I was initially confused when, viewing the product variation class, I found a filter with a similar structure that essentially duplicates the functionality for certain cases that don't apply here.)

Comment: Great post, I cross-read it and i'll try it out ASAP. Thank you.

Comment: 6 hours to go, and all I've gotten is someone for some reason downgrading this answer! Oh well, was educational for me...

Comment: I did not even have the time. I lost focus. Let me at least give you your rep. Feel free to contact me I'm often in JavaScript/PHP chat rooms.